# Cannot boot from USB or DVD _Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: boot

hope somebody has any original ideas on my particular problem..
I have downloaded and successfully installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64-bit to my new Laptop and am having minor problems with speed etc. Thus I was going to install the 32-bit version, however my laptop simply won't boot from either my USB or DVD. I've already changed the boot sequence and tried different USB ports as well as created another bootable USB stick (different brand), with no success. There are no error messages or anything like that, the Laptop just smoothly boots up to the "old" version I had installed before. 
Bit of data on my laptop (no idea if this is relevant):

Acer Aspire ES1-711-C07Z
Hard drive 1000 GB (5.400 U/min) 2,5“ S-ATA
Processor: Intel® Celeron Quad-Core Prozessor N2940 (4x 1,83 - 2,27 GHz, 2 MB L2 Cache)
Ram: 4 GB DDR3

I am no tech-genius, so I'd appreciate it if you could dumb it down as much as possible for me ;) 
Let me know if you need any additional data :)
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you've gone through the whole process of making a bootable usb without any errors? How did you set your boot sequence?

Comment: Yes, there were no error messages during the four times I created the bootable USB. I set the boot sequence to USB first- basically tried them all, because there were different sorts of USB options available. Obviously switched it to DVD/CD when I tried booting from the DVD. As I understand the boot follows through to all bootable options untill it arrives at one that works (which would be my harddrive) right?

Comment: In my BIOS (Award, I believe) setting the priority to a certain type of media doesn't help - you have to enter a menu called hard disk priority and set it up there - try it :) And what you say is correct, if for example you normally boot from CD and there's no CD, then it goes to the next available option.

Comment: I have no such entry in my Bios (to be honest, compared to other laptops I had, my options in this one are pretty limited)